# Generating different types of serial key for different subscriptions for java application

Tags: java, web-services, trialware

I want to add a serial key feature in my java application where the client has to purchase key for a certain peroid (1 month, 6 months, 1 year, etc) after that the client should not be allowed to use the premium features of the software. Its just like windows software where we are allowed to buy serial key and use the premimum features of the software. How would I do that. I have seen some other relavant questions but didn't get the working answer

Answer (score 0):

1. create an encrypted serial key with the information you need, i.e expiry date, type, etc
2. program should decrypt at startup, and do necessary checks
3. have a method call check if the client is using an expired licence, if so, disable certain features.

However there are many ways to do this, and you should in no way rely on this being foolproof, if someone wants to break it, they will.

rather focus on making your application as awesome as possible.

Comment: well what if the user change the date and time settings of his machine? This method wont work. Is it possible by using web services??

Comment: absolutely, making the app call home is a good method, but some users might not have internet...

Comment: Well internet is a must have for the application which enables users to click a link in the application to but the serial key isn't it?

Comment: Please isn't there anyone who can help me out of this? I want to use web services but I don't have enough idea for that